# How to get the list of resources loaded by a webview?

Tags: android, webview

I need to list all remote resources loaded by a webview page for debugging purposes.
For example something like this in development tool of commons browser:

[image]

I would like to get the list of resources, their URL, the response code (or error) and if the resources were cached or not.

The main goal of this debugging is to detect if and which resource is cached or not correctly loaded.

Comment: do you have used the WebViewAssetLoader  and LocalContentWebViewClient in your code ???

Comment: show please your code , I think you use Android studio

Answer (score 0):

I send you a example in java language :

```
WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
.addPathHandler("/assets/", new     WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
.addPathHandler("/res/", new     WebViewAssetLoader.ResourcesPathHandler(this))
.build();
webView.setWebViewClient(new LocalContentWebViewClient(assetLoader));
```

and for more information , read this website :

> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader

and if you share your code , will be better.